# Prevent console of sub processes from force closing

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating 5 sub processes from my main process & waiting for all of them to finish. Each of the sub process creates its own console window. What i want to do is to disable the close button of the console windows created by the sub processes. I couldn't find any resources to do that.

- How to keep the console of the sub process open such that if user press the close button of the console it doesn't close?
- `GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode)` is always returning false & the last error code from `GetLastError()` is 5. But  value of `exitCode` is showing the correct value. Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

wstring to_wstring(const string& str)
{
    std::wstring ws;
    ws.assign(str.begin(), str.end());
    return ws;
}

vector<PROCESS_INFORMATION> v;

int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    int noOfProcess = 4;
    for (int i = 1; i <= noOfProcess; i++) {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

        auto ws = to_wstring("D:\\programming\\test.exe");
        TCHAR *cmd;
        cmd = new TCHAR[ws.length() + 10];
        _tcscpy_s(cmd, ws.length() + 1, ws.c_str());

        // Start the child process.
        if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
            cmd,        // Command line
            NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
            true,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,              // No creation flags
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
            &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
            )
        {
            printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
            return 0;
        }

        cout << "Started Process " << pi.hProcess << endl;
        v.push_back(pi);
    }
    while (v.size()) {
        for (auto it = v.begin(), next_it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it = next_it) {
            next_it = it; it++;
            PROCESS_INFORMATION &pi = *it;
            DWORD exitCode = 0;
            if (GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode) == FALSE)
            {
                // Always return error code 5 but exitcode is set to correct value
                cout << GetLastError() << endl;
            }
            if (exitCode == STILL_ACTIVE)
                continue;
            cout << "Finished Process " << pi.hProcess << " With exit code " << exitCode << endl;
            // Close process and thread handles.
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            v.erase(it);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One obvious solution would be not to create new consoles for your child processes. Is there a specific reason you need the new consoles in the first place?

Comment: Yes, i need to show output from the exe in these console.

Comment: My usual solution for this would be to redirect output from the children into the parent console, and log output by prefixing it with the child's index, for example: `child 001: example of output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try this way to disable the close button in the sub process(the moment when you want to disable close button).

   `DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);`
2. According to the MSDN doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess), The handle of `GetExitCodeProcess()` must have the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access right. Open the Process with PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION.

   `OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, true, pi.dwProcessId);`
3. I have test your code, There is an error in it. When the `v.size() = 1`, `it++` will go out of the vector, then `*it` throw an exception. 
   After v.erase(it),you'd better break and restart the for loop(add the `break;` after `v.erase(it);`).